# In MongoDB, should users and usage data be in separate collections?

Tags: mongodb

I'm going to be tracking usage data (clicks, emails...etc) for users of my product.  I'm using MongoDB and I'm wondering if I even need a separate collection for the usage data.  Why not just keep added the data to the user documents using embedded documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why not just keep added the data to the user documents using embedded documents?

1. This will make writes to a very sensitive collection from parts of the code that are relatively insecure, thereby coupling parts of the code that shouldn't be coupled
2. It will trigger a high number of writes on an otherwise mostly-read collection, severely increasing fragmentation
3. This kind of data (clicks, emails, page views, etc.) has a very wide distribution, i.e. some users are mostly inactive, others are highly active, thus the size of documents will be largely spread and could exceed the maximum document size
   3a. by the same token, attackers could flood your user collection
4. additionally, this slows down fetching users because there's more data to fetch. Even when using a projection, the database will still have to read the data from disk or RAM

In a nutshell: you can do it for small systems with low nonfunctional requirements, but I don't recommend it for anything serious.

Comment: Thank you!    Very clear.  So I guess that means I'll need code that "joins" the data as I need it.  Maybe add a "count" to each user document for the important metrics?

Comment: Well, the joins should be simple, either for a user (`db.metrics.find({userId:myUserId})`) or groups of users (`db.metrics.find({userId: { $in : myUserIds } })`). I wouldn't keep a count in the user itself (again, coupling and frequent updates), but it makes sense to store usage data in a kind of level-of detail collection (daily stats for the last 7 days or so, then weekly, then monthly). Of course that depends on the use case, but generally, you'll want to avoid to aggregate the entire event collection if any possible